# How to run a script

Tags: bash, scripts

I downloaded the DocFetcher package for Linux. The readme says "Launch the program by double-clicking on ... DocFetcher-GTK3.sh." When I do that, the program doesn't launch, nonetheless though I've made sure the executable flag has been set on the file. Instead, the file opens in gedit.

The program does, however, launch when I run the command ./DocFetcher-GTK3.sh in the terminal.

What do I have to change to get the program to launch by double-clicking on DocFetcher-GTK3.sh?

Comment: What is the Shebang in the .sh file? That might be causing your problems if you don't have one or your system doesn't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Further searching located the answer. I used dconf-editor to make script executable. It wasn't sufficient to tick the relevant box that made the file executable after right-clicking on the file.